# asyncio only processes one file at a time

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm working a program to upload (large) files to a remote SFTP-server, while also calculating the file's SHA256. The uploads are slow, and the program is supposed to open multiple SFTP-connections.

Here is the main code:

```py
async def bwrite(fd, buf):
    log.debug('Writing %d bytes to %s', len(buf), fd)
    fd.write(buf)

async def digester(digest, buf):
    log.debug('Updating digest %s with %d more bytes', digest, len(buf))
    digest.update(buf)

async def upload(fNames, SFTP, rename):

    for fName in fNames:
        inp = open(fName, "rb", 655360)
        log.info('Opened local %s', fName)
        digest = hashlib.sha256()
        rName = rename % os.path.splitext(fName)[0]
        out = SFTP.open(rName, "w", 655360)
...
        while True:
            buf = inp.read(bsize)
            if not buf:
                break
            await bwrite(out, buf)
            await digester(digest, buf)

        inp.close()
        out.close()
...

for i in range(0, len(clients)):
    fNames = args[(i * chunk):((i + 1) * chunk)]
    log.debug('Connection %s: %d files: %s',
        clients[i], len(fNames), fNames)
    uploads.append(upload(fNames, clients[i], Rename))

log.info('%d uploads initiated, awaiting completion', len(uploads))
results = asyncio.gather(*uploads)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(results)
loop.close()
```

The idea is for multiple `upload` coroutines to run "in parallel" -- each using its own separate SFTP-connection -- pushing out one or more files to the server.

It even works -- but only a single `upload` is running at any time. I expected multiple ones to get control -- while their siblings `await`s the `bwrite` and/or the `digester`. What am I doing wrong?

(Using Python-3.6 on FreeBSD-11, if that matters... The program is supposed to run on RHEL7 eventually...)

Comment: RHEL6? That's been completely out of support for nearly two years now. For that matter, Python 3.6 stopped being supported entirely last month. Is there a reason you can't use something released in the last five years?

Comment: It is RHEL*7*, actually -- I just fixed it. No, upgrading is out of the question -- big firms don't move as fast as home computers, for better or worse...

Comment: Python isn't written to be aysnc stem to stern. Async has been bolted on. It up to the programmer to stay away from non-async blocking calls. It may be easier to use `threading` or `multiprocessing` on this code than try to make it async.

Answer (score 1):

If no awaiting is involved, then no parallelism can occur. `bwrite` and `digester`, while declared `async`, perform no async operations (not launching or creating coroutines that can be awaited); if you removed the `async` in their name and removed the `await` where they're called, the code would behave identically.

The *only* time `asyncio` can get you benefits is when:

1. There is a blocking operation involved, *and*
2. Said blocking operation is *designed* for `asyncio` use (or involves a file descriptor that can be rewrapped for said purposes)

Your `bwrite` isn't doing that (it's doing normal blocking I/O on `SFTP` objects, which doesn't appear to be `async`-friendly; if it was async, your failure to either return the future it produced, or `await` it yourself, would usually mean it does nothing, barring the off-chance it self-scheduled a task internally), your reads from the input file aren't either (which is fine; normally, changing blocking I/O to asyncio for local file access isn't beneficial; it's all being buffered, at user level and kernel level, so you almost never block on the writes). Nor is your `digester` (hashing operations are CPU bound; it never makes sense to make them `async` unless they're being done with actual async stuff).

Since the two `await`s in `upload` are effectively synchronous (they don't return anything that, when `await`ed, would actually block on actual asynchronous tasks), `upload` itself is effectively synchronous (it will never, under any circumstances, return control to the event loop before it completes). So even though all the other tasks are in the event loop queue, raring to go, the event loop itself has to wait until the running task blocks in an async-friendly way (with `await` on something that actually does background work while blocked), which never happens, and the tasks just get run sequentially, one after the other.

If an async-friendly version of your `SFTP` module exists, that might allow you to gain some benefit. But without it, you're probably better off using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` or `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` to do preemptive multitasking (which will swap out threads whenever they release the GIL, forcibly swapping between bytecodes if they don't release the GIL for awhile). That will get you parallelism on *any* blocking I/O (async-friendly or not), and, if the data is large enough, on the hashing work as well (`hashlib` is one of the only Python built-ins I know of that releases the GIL for CPU-bound work, if the data to be hashed is large enough; extension modules releasing the GIL is the only way multithreaded CPython can do more than one core's worth of CPU-bound work in a single process, even on multicore systems).

Comment: The SFTP-module is the beloved Paramiko. Is it asyncio-friendly? Can it be made so? Thanks!

Comment: @MikhailT.: Doesn't look like it, but I could have missed something. Looks like someone wrote [AsyncSSH](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for that purpose though.

Comment: @MikhailT.: Just found [this still open Paramiko request](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/389) from before `asyncio` even existed, proposing some form of cooperative concurrency support. Never seems to have gone anywhere.